# How to setup Java-Home and Path in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: system-installation, java, openjdk, jdk

we are new to `Ubuntu`.Recently we changed my server OS to `ubuntu 12.04` from windows 7 . every one have their own login details. one of my college installed `Open-Jdk7`. I asked him, where you installed `JAVA`, then he suggested to switch the following directory

```
su root
cd /usr/lib/Jvm
```

Totally 3 folders are there in JVM folder. names are.

1. java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
2. java-7-openjdk-amd64
3. java-7-openjdk-common

generally, If you install `Java` in `Windows`, we will get 2 folder. 1 folder is for `JDK`and another points to `JRE`.

but, in Ubuntu we have 3 folders. is it right?

for my conformation, whether he installed correctly or not. I open `Terminal`. I run the following 2 commands

```
 javac
 java -version
```

both commands are working fine.

now I want to set-up `Java-Home and Path` for all users at same place.because everyone is working on `Application server`.

Can anyone explain step-by-step.

Thanks.

Comment: The best way to setup environment variables for all users is editing `/etc/environment` file. It has pretty simple syntax. And to setup user-specific environment variable you should edit `~/.bashrc` file. Add the `export VAR=value` to the end of this file.

Comment: I mention like this.

`PATH=PredefinePaths:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin`
`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"`.
I didn't mention any special charachers in between Path and JAVA-HOME variables.
Is it right, What I did

Comment: I see you came from Windows world :) There is no need to change PATH variable. Just add JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME if some application requires them.

Answer (score 2):

Installation of Oracle Java:

1. Donwload the tarball from Oracle website
2. unzip it using this command:

   ```
   sudo tar -xvpzf fileName -C /installation_folder_name`
   ```
3. change the files permission and ownership
4. add the following two lines in `/etc/profile`

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/home/abu/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
5. restart the machine and check by `java -version` and `javac -version`

Answer (score 0):

Edit the system Path file /etc/profile

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/profile # always use -H when you sudo a gui program or anything else which might write config files to the $HOME directory.
```

Add following lines in end

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

For complete installation guide.. http://javaandme.com/

Comment: i tried this but still got the same error

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

then add these lines

```
JAVA_HOME = ":usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin"
CLASSPATH = ":usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin:/home/something etc whatever you want etc" ( separated by semicolon )
```

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should point to a java installation folder, not its `bin` subfolder. And what's with those colons?