# Android Studio not working - tools.jar classpath error

Tags: java, home-directory

I have just downloaded the Android Studio and when I try to run `./studio.sh` it gives me an error of

```
'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE
```

I have checked `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64` this folder `java` is there and I have set the environment variables  in

```
/etc/environment
```

as

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/"
```

but still, the same error is coming, Please help me out,

after saving this file, if I check

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

nothing comes and when I try

```
source /etc/environment
```

it comes as

```
JAVA_HOME: command not found
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: try this link: [How to setup Java-Home and Path in Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/321422/how-to-setup-java-home-and-path-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: still same error is coming, i have downloaded the Java version again from oracle webiste as suggested on the link, and install it and moved to lib/jvm, but same error.  echo $JAVA_HOME is giving nothing.again..

Comment: did you add PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin? could you post your /etc/environment file?

Comment: Seems you install only **JRE**. Visit related **[question](http://askubuntu.com/q/122133/181228)**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the same error when trying to run the android-studio beta installation. I tried various options, but the one that worked for me was:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Didn't have to do anything else.

But, I am surprised that

```
java -version
```

listed the same 3 lines before and after the jdk install:

```
java version "1.7.0_55"  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.13.10.1)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

and

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

outputs blanks, but now the android-studio is running.

Comment: wth :O ... it just worked... need nothing to do... just install open-jdk-7

Comment: ohh i had  a doubt earlier... but i was wrong ... working flawlessly

Answer (score 2):

Check the [most liked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601334/error-to-run-android-studio). If java is already installed and want to change the priority then

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

For me there was a problem with some certificates (seems to be a java bug).
I fixed it with the following ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439905/is-the-cacerts-file-missing-in-ubuntu-15-10-and-openjdk-8-jdk/33440168#33440168)):

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I performed:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Hope it helps!